# Get the Triangular Polygon where the Ray Point intersected

Tags: ios, 3d, metal

I am rendering a 3D Obj model in iOS. http://metalbyexample.com/picking-hit-testing/. I am following the above Tutorial written by WM to find the hit point in the 3D model. Using the above link I can find the intersecting point with 3D model. I want to find the triangular polygon where I touched and I want to find the UV coordinates in the Image texture. How can I do that..

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Comment: Unless you have some kind of secondary acceleration structure, like an octree or a kd-tree containing the primitives in the mesh being intersection-tested, the way to do this is to iterate over the primitives (triangles) in the mesh and perform a ray-triangle test on each one, noting the closest hit. You can then use the primitive's vertices and the intersection point (expressed in barycentric coordinates) to determine the uv coordinates at that point. There are hundreds of resources on how to do this available on the Web.