# Find if 3D Circular Edge Lies Inside 3D Planar polygon of N Sides in 3D space

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, geometry

I have a scenario where I need to determine if the circular edge is in the vicinity of the opposite face in 3D space. I want to write a C# code for this. I want to know the best algorithm to do this.

[image: Click on Image for more details]

Note: I am not good in mathematics so please excuse me if someone feels it is a silly question :-)

Comment: If you can figure out if a point (say the center of the circle) is on side side or the other of a plane (dot products), then adding a circle to it shouldn't be too hard.  My guess is that you should be able to check this with 2 points (circle center + radius projected along a vector which is the"closest" edge and circle center - radius along same vector).    If neither point is behind the plane, no collide, 1 point would be an intersection, both points would mean circle within the other shape.  I would have to puzzle out the exact mechanics, but this feels right.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Can you explain to me in more detail? It is over my head.

Comment: Start with googling to see how to detect if a point is on a near or far side of a plane.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688232/check-which-side-of-a-plane-points-are-on - or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56832882/get-the-triangular-polygon-where-the-ray-point-intersected